# CSV files - can't print specific values/entities from my csv

Tags: python

For a game I am planning, I want to create a piece of code that will write one specific value from a list of all the items in my game into the player's inventory (e.g.: player gets item "potion", which would require searching the items CSV for potion and then putting the relevant info into the CSV). Whenever I run my code however I get the error "TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable".

I've tried researching and asking peers but the closest I've gotten to a clear solution is someone mentioning writing to a list from the CSV, but they didn't explain much more. Hoping someone could elaborate on this for me or provide an easier solution.

```
import csv

allitems = open("ALLITEMS.csv")
checkallitems = csv.reader(allitems)

playerinv = open("INVENTORY.csv")
checkinv = csv.reader(playerinv)

item = input("")

for x in checkallitems:
    print(allitems[x][0])
    if item == allitems[x][0]:
        playerinv.write(allitems[x][0]+"\n")
allitems.close()
playerinv.close()
```

Comment: Actually, there's a few things that don't make sense here. None of the files are open for writing. `allitems[x][0]` doesn't make sense because it's a file object that you're trying to use as a dictionary, and then index as though a list, but also you should be using the CSV module to write data back out

Comment: Not sure if that is cause of your problem, but your `open`s are missing second argument i.e. mode which should be `w` for writing and `r` for reading. You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp

Comment: @Daweo if the OP opens in write mode with `w` they will wipe their own files. To open for reading - that's the default argument so no need to actually specify `r`. They need a different setup here. Also, I've seen several articles about Python in W3Schools that are plainly _wrong_ so I would recommend not referring to them for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `allitems` is a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) returned by [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and the statement `for x in checkallitems` iterates over the lines of such file so, you are trying to use a `list` as index in that file. Also, you have to open `INVENTORY.csv` in **write mode** (using 'w' or 'a') to be able to write to it.

Just use `x` instead of `allitems[x]`. The snippet below should do the job:

```
for x in checkallitems:
    if item == x[0]:
        playerinv.write(x[0]+"\n")
```

So, the complete code could be:

#### Code

```
import csv

allitems = open("ALLITEMS.csv")
checkallitems = csv.reader(allitems)

playerinv = open("INVENTORY.csv", 'a')
checkinv = csv.reader(playerinv)

item = input("")

for x in checkallitems:
    if item == x[0]: # Check if the item is equal to the first item on the list
        playerinv.write(x[0]+"\n")

allitems.close()
playerinv.close()
```

I dont know what do you want to accomplish, so I tried to stick as much as possible to your code.

If you want to only write the item provided by the user if it is found the current list of items, this would do the job:

#### Code

```
import csv

allitems = open("ALLITEMS.csv")
checkallitems = csv.reader(allitems)

playerinv = open("INVENTORY.csv", 'a')
checkinv = csv.reader(playerinv)

item = input("")

for x in checkallitems:
    if item in x: # Check if the item is in the current list
        playerinv.write(item +"\n")

allitems.close()
playerinv.close()
```

I hope this can help you. Let me know if any of this worked for you, otherwise, tell me what went wrong.